# You keep winning, why?

Tags: python

so I am trying to do simple rolling of the dice to see if you win(excuse if something is indented wrong, the copy n paste is kinda wonky, here is a pastbin if you would rather have that http://pastebin.com/thg7ruT1). I am not exactly sure what is happen but when I run the YouMightWin function, no matter what StanDice's outcome is it always says "You Win!" even if it rolls less than 6. I am not sure what looks like it should work to me, at least from other things I've played around. If you can help thanks.

```
def StanDice():
    num_dice = 2
    num_sides = 6
    rand_num = random.randint(1, num_dice*num_sides)
    print rand_num

def YouMightWin():
    Ans = raw_input("Roll the dice? [Y/N]: ")
    Ans = Ans.lower()
    dice_roll = StanDice()

    if Ans in ("y" or "yes"):
       print dice_roll, "This is the Dice"
       if dice_roll < 6:
          print "You win!"
       elif dice_roll > 6:
          print "You lose!"
      else:
          print "Something went wrong!"
    elif Ans in ('n' or 'no'):
        print "Are you sure you don't want to roll?"
        YouMightWin()
    else:
        print "Something went in the main if statement"
```

Comment: You need to `return rand_num` at the end of StanDice. Also, this isn't how dice work.

Comment: Note that when you roll n>1 dice, you can never get the outcome `1`

Comment: Also, `Ans in ("y" or "yes")` is going to error out on you. You might be looking for `Ans in ("y", "yes")`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget `'y' or 'yes'` will evaluate to `True` since non-empty strings are considered `True` by Python. Since `Ans` will likely not be `None` or `False` the statement evaluates to `if True in (True)`

Comment: @IanAuld: you correctly point out that it ultimately evaluates to `if True in True`. However, since neither `bool`s nor `int`s (depending on the python version, this distinction is very important) have a `__contains__` method, the error will be seen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Inspector, I haven't ran into any errors with the code that I've noticed, why what should I be looking for? I have never used a contains method before, should I check to make sure there isn't anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `print`ing the value of `rand_num` instead of `return`ing it, so the function returns `None`, which is less than 6.

That said, your dice are too naive-- real don't have an equal chance of rolling 2 and 7. Check out a probability table. You should roll each die independently and add them together instead.

Comment: `rand_num = sum([random.randint(1,num_sides) for i in range(num_dice)])`